# Forbid copy-construction of base class

Tags: c++11, copy-constructor, smart-pointers, base-class

I'm wanting to quickly implement what some call an "owner pointer", that is, a smart pointer ensuring unique ownership semantics, while providing "observer" pointers that don't keep the object alive, but can test whether it is.

The most straightforward way I'm trying to do it is to subclass `std::shared_ptr`, and disable its copy-construction so that no other pointer can actually share the object.

This is what I have for now :

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct owner_ptr : public std::shared_ptr<T> {

    // Import constructors
    using std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr;

    // Disable copy-construction
    owner_ptr(owner_ptr<T> const&) = delete;

    // Failed attempt at forbidding what comes next
    operator std::shared_ptr<T> const&() = delete;
};

struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "Hello Foo\n";
    }

    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "G'bye Foo\n";
    }

    void talk() {
        std::cout << "I'm talkin'\n";
    }
};

owner_ptr<Foo> fooPtr(new Foo);

int main(int, char**) {

    // This should not compile, but it does.
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> sptr = fooPtr;

    // Simple tests
    fooPtr->talk();
    (*fooPtr).talk();

    // Confirmation that two pointers are sharing the object (it prints "2").
    std::cout << sptr.use_count() << '\n';
}
```

I've been pulling my hair on this one. How do I forbid the copy-construction of a `std::shared_ptr` from my `owner_ptr` ? I'm not fond of inheriting privately and then importing everything from `std::shared_ptr`...

Comment: You really want to use composition instead of inheritance here. Especially not a public base. That's the source of all your troubles.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'd be forwarding everything to said member, which is quite the same as what I state in my last sentence. I'd do it as a last resort if nothing else can be done, but I'm not fond of it.

Comment: so, you want to create something like `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @BЈовић `std::unique_ptr` does not provide observer pointers, which is the main feature I need.

Comment: what exactly is "observer pointer"?

Comment: @BЈовић see my first paragraph. It's basically a `std::weak_ptr`, but these can't reference `std::unique_ptr`s (and for very good reasons).

Comment: isn't it better to create something for `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @BЈовић I don't think it can be done : the cleanest way of being able to tell that an object is dead is to leave a "tombstone" when deallocating it, that observer pointers can test for. `std::unique_ptr` can't do that. Edit : and to be clear, I could code it from scratch but I'd rather not.

Comment: I'm curious. What happens if your observer pointer dies between checking it is alive and using it? weak_ptr is safe because you have to create a shared_ptr from it to use it but I assume you don't want to follow the same pattern otherwise your owner pointer does not have unique ownership.

Comment: `std::weak_ptr` has `lock` to create `std::shared_ptr`s from it. And that you can't prevent.

Comment: @ChrisDrew even though it should not happen in single-threaded applications, I though about throwing a specific exception from `operator->` or `operator*` if the object is dead. That way the user code just gives up whatever it was doing on the object. BЈовић: The `weak_ptr` would also be wrapped. Note that I somehow had forgotten about `lock()`, that complexifies things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think subclassing `std::shared_ptr` is the way to go. If you really wanted to do it properly I think you should implement it yourself including all the reference counting. Implementing a smart pointer is not actually *that* hard.

However, in most cases, if you just want something that meets your needs use composition.

I was curious about what you were trying to do,  I'm not convinced it is a good idea but I had a go at implementing a `OwnerPointer` and `ObserverPointer` pair using composition:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  Foo() {std::cout << "Hello Foo\n"; }
  ~Foo() { std::cout << "G'bye Foo\n"; }
  void talk() { std::cout << "I'm talkin'\n"; }
};

template <class T>
class ObserverPointer;  // Forward declaration.

template<class T>
class OwnerPointer;  // Forward declaration.

// RAII object that can be obtained from ObserverPointer
// that ensures the ObserverPointer does not expire.
// Only operation is to test validity.
template <class T>
class ObserverLock {
 friend ObserverPointer<T>;
 private:
  std::shared_ptr<T> impl_;
  ObserverLock(const std::weak_ptr<T>& in) : impl_(in.lock()) {}
 public:
  // Movable.
  ObserverLock(ObserverLock&&) = default;
  ObserverLock& operator=(ObserverLock&&) = default;

  // Not copyable.
  ObserverLock& operator=(const ObserverLock&) = delete;
  ObserverLock(const ObserverLock&) = delete;

  // Test validity.
  explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return impl_ != nullptr;} 
};

template <class T>
class ObserverPointer {
 private:
  std::weak_ptr<T> impl_;
  T*               raw_;
 public:
  ObserverPointer(const OwnerPointer<T>& own) noexcept : impl_(own.impl_), raw_(own.get()) {}

  T* get() const { return raw_; }
  T* operator->() const { return raw_; }
  T& operator*() const { return *raw_; }

  ObserverPointer() : impl_(), raw_(nullptr) { }
  ObserverPointer(const ObserverPointer& in) = default;
  ObserverPointer(ObserverPointer&& in) = default;
  ObserverPointer& operator=(const ObserverPointer& in) = default;
  ObserverPointer& operator=(ObserverPointer&& in) = default; 

  bool expired() { return impl_.expired(); }  
  ObserverLock<T> lock() { return ObserverLock<T>(impl_); }
};

template <class T>
struct OwnerPointer {    
 friend ObserverPointer<T>;    
 private:
  std::shared_ptr<T> impl_;
 public:

  // Constructors
  explicit OwnerPointer(T* in) : impl_(in) {}
  template<class Deleter>
  OwnerPointer(std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>&& in) : impl_(std::move(in)) { }
  OwnerPointer(std::shared_ptr<T>&& in) noexcept : impl_(std::move(in)) { }
  OwnerPointer(OwnerPointer<T>&&) noexcept = default;  
  OwnerPointer(OwnerPointer<T> const&) = delete;

  // Assignment operators
  OwnerPointer& operator=(OwnerPointer<T> const&) = delete;
  OwnerPointer& operator=(OwnerPointer<T>&&) = default;

  T* get() const { return impl_.get(); }
  T* operator->() const { return impl_.get(); }
  T& operator*() const { return *impl_; }

  explicit operator ObserverPointer<T>() const noexcept { return ObserverPointer<T>(impl_);}
  explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return impl_;}
};

// Convenience function equivalent to make_shared
template <class T, class... Args>
OwnerPointer<T> make_owner(Args && ...args) {
  return OwnerPointer<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main() {
  auto owner = make_owner<Foo>();
  ObserverPointer<Foo> observer = owner; 
  auto lock = observer.lock();
  if (lock)
   observer->talk();
}
```

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fbb7059ac50b5c3)

It probably needs some work and it doesn't offer the full feature set of std::shared_ptr & std::weak_ptr but then in most cases it won't need to, just create what you need.

I've stretched the definition of "unique ownership" by offering an RAII `ObserverLock` object that can only be used to keep the `ObserverPointer` alive. Technically it "owns" the pointer but it is very restricted in what it can do and you can't create more than one "OwnerPointer".

Comment: While it does not answer my question, it does solve my problem. I was about to roll my sleeves and implement it myself, but I wouldn't have thought of `ObserverLock` as you designed it. Thanks !